# Критические секции. C++

Tags: c++

Здраствуйте, как правильно поставить критическую секцию в такой функции?

```
DWORD WINAPI Set1(LPVOID){
    EnterCriticalSection (&cs) ;
    for (int i=0; i<amount; i++){
        if (Flowers[i]==2 ){
            Flowers[i]=1;
            cout << "Set1 ";
            cout << endl;

        }
    }
LeaveCriticalSection (&cs);
ExitThread(0);
return 0;

}
```

Comment: Второй выход и КС будет корректным

Comment: Нехорошо изменять суть вопроса после появления ответа на него. Рекомендую добавить изначальный вопрос в примечания в конце тела вопроса.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Правильно — за пределами цикла.

```
DWORD WINAPI Set1(LPVOID)
{
    EnterCriticalSection (&cs);
    for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
    {
        if (Flowers[i] == 2)
        {
            Flowers[i] = 1;
            std::cout << "Set1 " << endl;
        }
    }

    LeaveCriticalSection (&cs);
    ExitThread(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Освобождение секции внутри цикла чревато минимум двумя вещами:

1. Если в массиве не окажется ни одного элемента, равного двум, критическая секция не будет освобождена.
2. А если в массиве будет больше одного такого элемента, критическая секция будет высвобождена больше раз, чем вы её захватили.

И да, зачем вам нужен `return 0;` после `ExitThread(0);`? Вторая функция и так обеспечивает безусловный выход из потока.

Comment: Ещё есть вариант заключить вход в критическую секцию в тело цикла. Но не знаю, насколько он правильный.

Comment: @Byulent, зависит от того, что автор хочет этой секцией защитить.

Comment: Как обеспечить работу 2 потоков с критическими секциями? У меня работает один поток.

Comment: @HiHello, `cout` внутри себя тоже имеет блокировку. Может быть, дело в ней?

Comment: @Arhad думаю что так и есть. Убрав cout << endl; заработал 2 поток.